# Can I use a function gas cost to calculate network utilisation?

Tags: blockchain, gas, gas-limit, arbitrum

I’m developing a governance DApp and need to research various blockchains and their scalability. One of the ways I’m doing this is by estimating the gas price of all the smart contract functions that'll be called. Subsequently, I’m looking at the gas limit of a block to see how these 2 parameters compare in order to see if a chain can handle a peak load of X amount of users calling a function at exactly the same time. However, I wasn’t able to find any information on this on Arbitrum. Do I misunderstand how Arbitrum works? Can anyone point me in the right direction on where I could find this information?

Also, is my understanding of gas cost as a way to see the load it puts on a chain correct?